# change multiple values in a vector

Tags: r

I have the location of certain values I would like to change in a vector for two values if 
positive or negative.

```
library(extremevalues)
x<-c(-1,3,4,5,-7,-6,1,-3,0,0,90,8,6,7,25,3,4,-2,1,3,-5,4,6,-8,5,-7,4,-5,5,44,6,2,3,-4,5,-6,1,2,
-35,4,4,-3,2,-1,2,4,-5,8,-35)
g<-getOutliers(x, method="I")

#location values in the vector
s<-c(g$iRight,g$iLeft)
s
[1] 11 15 30 39 49

#Values to change depending on the sign of the element in x. If positive then a if 
negative then b

a<-mean(x > 0)
a
[1] 0.6326531

b<-mean(x < 0)
b
[1] 0.3265306
```

I know how to replace the values one by one by using the replace function. However as the number of locations and values can change if another vector x would be used with different values, how would you structure an expression to instruct changing some elements of x in the locations given by the vector s in x by the values of a and b depending if the original values were positive or negative. (if positive a will be replacing the element in x, if negative b will be replacing the element in x)

Thank you

Comment: You have not described at all what you want `a` and `b` to be. By the way you have written them, they are simply a value between 0 and 1. You also have not described the relationship between `a`, `b` and `s`. You should also describe the output `s` from the `getOutliers` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[s] <- ifelse(x[s] < 0, mean(x < 0), mean(x > 0))`